# EAS build gives: Invalid `RNGestureHandler.podspec` file: undefined method `exists?'

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, react-native-gesture-handler, eas

Recently, when I `yarn eas build` my expo project I have started failing with

```
[INSTALL_PODS] Using Expo modules
[INSTALL_PODS] [Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
...
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] Invalid `RNGestureHandler.podspec` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.
...
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  -------------------------------------------
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  
[INSTALL_PODS]  >  isUserApp = File.exists?(File.join(__dir__, "..", "..", "node_modules", "react-native", "package.json"))
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  if isUserApp
[INSTALL_PODS]  #  -------------------------------------------
```

I don't build locally often (remote builds on the Expo servers do fine) so any number of things might have triggered this over the past several weeks, including a migration from  an Intel MBP to an M2 MBA, but I wonder if there's an obvious reason that someone has experience with. The error suggests there's something wrong with the podfile's use of an undefined method. But the [suggestions for addressing this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20707) I've found online involve all kinds of tweaking that are way beyond what I'm familiar with. My experience with Expo/EAS just been to be sure to

```
brew install cocoapods fastlane
```

and don't involve much more than that. Ideally I'd like to avoid messing with special gem installations of the sort suggested as quick fixes.

So the question is: is this indeed just a bug in a podfile (use of a deprecated method) that will eventually get fixed?

---

UPDATE: Broadly it seems that the answer is "yes": this does get fixed in later versions of the affected packages, *but* those packages are not officially compatible with Expo. If I update them to versions that allow building, then I get warnings:

```
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] [16:17:37] Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] [16:17:37]  - react-native-gesture-handler - expected version: ~2.8.0 - actual version installed: 2.9.0
[RUN_EXPO_DOCTOR] [16:17:37]  - react-native-reanimated - expected version: ~2.12.0 - actual version installed: 2.14.4
```

so the question becomes: when will Expo officially support package versions required to successfully build?

Answer (score 36):

This issue happens because Ruby `3.2` removed deprecated function `File.exists?` ([reference](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.2.html#removals))

First remove `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`

Then install newer versions of both libraries

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler@^2.9.0
npm install react-native-reanimated@^2.14.4
```

Then run `cd ios` and `pod install`.

Answer (score 9):

1. Install `2.9.0` of `react-native-gesture-handler`. source: [comment](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/20757#issuecomment-1384301242)
2. Install `2.14.4` of `react-native-reanimated`. source: [comment](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/issues/2389#issuecomment-1458046584)
3. Remove `node_modules`, `yarn.lock` `ios/Podfile.lock`, `ios/build`, `ios/Pods`.
4. `yarn install && yarn ios`.

I've also updated cocoa pods to the latest `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

Answer (score 7):

install the new version for these libraries: **react-native-gesture-handler** & **react-native-reanimated**

```
npm install react-native-gesture-handler@^2.9.0
npm install react-native-reanimated@^2.14.4
```

then

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 4):

[Ruby 3.2.0 removed `File.exists?`](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.2.html#removals).

This issue was reported on [the expo repo on GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/20757).

The recommended fix is to [upgrade to expo@47.0.13](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/20757#issuecomment-1377921895).

Comment: That's what I thought too but my `package.json` has: `"expo": "^47.0.13"`

Comment: Ensure that `yarn install` has been run and that the installed package is up to date, then check the extended comments on the GitHub issue for more information on downstream packages.

Comment: Also I've tried downgrading ruby, but that hasn't worked either. Maybe there's some cruft somewhere that's getting in the way?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the packages directory and ran `yarn`.

Comment: Got it to build by using package versions that Expo doesn't (officially) support. See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me (running Node `v18.15` and Ruby `v3.3.1` and my build with Yarn `v1.22.19`) but I had to do all of the following:

Upgraded these dependencies:

```json
    "expo": "^47.0.14",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "4.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
```

Had to dump all these files:

```json
    yarn-lock.json
    /node_modules/
    /ios/podfile.lock
    /ios/build/
    /ios/Pods/
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `^` from package dot json for react native gesture handler

Then:

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install 
cd ios
pod install
```

And after that your pod will work fine.

It woks fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to downgrade the packages and was able to compile on macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 .

I used [RVM - Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io/) to install and use Ruby 3.1.4 (does not overwrite macOS standard Ruby version) to get Expo to compile with `npx expo run:ios` using the following package versions:

`"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0"`
`"react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0"`

I installed RVM with the following command, because there's also a [known issue related to openssl](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5033) regarding the compilation of rubies, and I followed [the solution presented on this comment on Github](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5033#issuecomment-760815125).

`arch -x86_64  rvm install 3.1.4 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1`